# Como criar um histórico de acesso dos Usuários de uma app Desktop

Tags: c#

Estou criando uma aplicação desktop (Sistema Comercial) usando C#. Tenho uma tabela de cadastro de Usuários no qual serão cadastrados todos os funcionários que farão login no sistema. Na tela de cadastro, gostaria de uma aba HISTÓRICO e listar todos os acessos daquele usuário durante um período...Seria semelhante à imagem abaixo:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para fazer armazenar o histórico, qual seria a melhor maneira:

1 - Criar uma tabela no mesmo Banco (ex: UsuarioHistorico) e gravar tudo nela;

2 - Gravar um arquivo log e lê-lo;

3 - ...Ou outra maneira de se fazer.

Desculpem se isso é uma pergunta tola, mas me preocupo muito em fazer sempre certo para depois não ter problemas e principalmente perder performance.

Obrigado :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cria uma tabela de log do sistema, não somente do usuário, e armazena os eventos nela...
em alguns sistemas, tenho uma estrutura com os seguintes dados:

```
data do servidor,
data do computador,
ip do computador,
id do usuario,
nome do computador,
tabela (usuarios,notas_fiscais,caixa,clientes,etc),
evento (insercao, alteracao, delecao,select,login, etc),
descricao (ex: alterou o nome do cliente de A para B),
id relacionado (pk do registro que sofreu alteração / inserção),
```

enfim, pode-se armazenar diversas informações, no seu caso, aplicado à essa estrutura, bastaria selecionar os eventos do usuario (id do usuario) com o evento login por exemplo.

funciona muito bem pra mim, espero que ajude.

Comment: Obrigado pela dica Rovann!!!